# Как лучше спроектировать базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Я в этом деле новичок, только начал изучение PHP. Прошу подсказать как мне лучше осуществить связь между таблицами внутри базы данных. Я буду делать базу данных для удобной работы с клиентами, будет поиск по заказчикам, их прошлые заказы и тд. Наверняка кто-то делал похожее, поделитесь пожалуйста, как вы это реализовали. На данный момент у меня 2 варианта. Либо искать связь через циклы. Например, в таблице заказчик будет id заказчика и через цикл перебором он будет искать этот же id в другой таблице и подставлять значения при совпадении, либо сделать связь через внешний ключ. Конечно же при внесении заказа должна быть выпадающая строка(условно, по прошлым адресам, на которые были сделаны заказы у конкретного заказчика). Будут уместны любые советы, желательно с примерами, дабы было от чего отталкиваться.
Набросал пример на листочке(извиняюсь за письменный вид)
[image: Пример]

Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Comment: вопрос хороший, а идеи странные.правильно спроектированная база - это половина успеха. так что это хорошо что ты спросил. но вот сам вопрос так себе. надо расписать подробно - что за заказчики, что за сторудники, что за коимпании, кто из них кому кто. по идее нужна еще таблица заказчиков и таблица адресов как минимум

Comment: Для того что бы спроектировать БД. Нужно сначала изучить нормальные формы есть. После чего изучить связи объектов и решить какая связь тебе нужна. 
Вот статья про связи https://habr.com/ru/post/488054/. Про нормальные формы в интернете тоже куча статей

Comment: @Ипатьев, условно, мы предоставляем какие-то услуги и нам поступают заказы на разные адреса (могут быть как новые, так и старые) от клиентов. Клиент может быть из какой-то компании, с которой у нас заключен договор, а может быть и без договора, значит, его не нужно будет связывать с компаниями. То есть, при внесении заказа я либо выберу сотрудника компании,  с которой у нас заключен договор, либо впишу нового, который ни с чем не связан(частный клиент). Я пока сам не понимаю как это лучше реализовать, было бы неплохо увидеть пример подобного решения.